# How to load static function with const variable as parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I have this a method that i want to get it's values from another method, but i can't since as a parameter i need to pass a class (FTL_Binding)  - with no comma between the parameters.

```
 public static function tag_flat_detail(FTL_Binding $tag)
    {

    $field = $tag->getAttribute('field');

    if ( ! is_null($field))
    {
        $detail = $tag->get('detail');

        if ( ! empty($detail[$field]))
        {
            return self::output_value($tag, $detail[$field]);
        }

        return self::show_tag_error(
            $tag,
            'The attribute <b>"field"</b> is not set'
        );

       }
    }
```

So I've tried this

```
 public static function tag_foo(FTL_Binding $tag)
{

    $foo = new FTL_Binding($tag);
    return self::tag_flat_detail(FTL_Binding($tag));

}
```

I'm getting this error ;

```
  Severity: 4096

 Message: Argument 1 passed to TagManager_Data::tag_foo() must be an 
 instance of FTL_Binding, none given, called in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\application\libraries\Tagmanager\Data.php on line 70 
and defined

 Filename: Tagmanager/Data.php

   Line Number: 122
```

I guess the instance $foo = new FTL_Binding($tag); is not working for some reason...

Comment: `self::tag_flat_detail($tag)` ? It only needs 1 parameter

Comment: Thanks - no - this method needs both class name and $tag - so the it needs to be like this "tag_flat_detail(FTL_Binding $tag)"

Comment: @RoyBarOn No it doesn't. `tag_flat_detail` expects exactly one parameter of type `FTL_Binding`. When calling the function you don't specify the type.

Comment: Well i've tried to pass only $tag - but i'm getting an error that the class is missing

Comment: I'd bet, the error you're getting explains that what you passed is not of the required type. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Yoshi - i've updated the question with the error - thanks

Comment: Ok, not as I expected, but similar. You're simply missing an argument to `new FTL_Binding`. You probably need it to be something like: `new FTL_Binding($someVal);`

Comment: @RoyBarOn you don't seem to understand what a "type declaration" (type hint) is. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: apokryfos , yoshi , thanks - i've updated the question

Comment: @RoyBarOn You need to read the error messages more deliberately. The current one explains that the argument to `TagManager_Data::tag_foo()` is not what it has to be. It's completely irrelevant (at least at the moment) what happens inside that method, because it's not even called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is declared, the types of its arguments can be declared by putting the type before the parameter name:

```
 public static function tag_foo(FTL_Binding $tag, $id = null)
```

Method `tag_foo()` expects two parameters:

- `$tag` must be of type `FTL_Binding`. If `FTL_Binding` is a [`class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) then `$tag` can be an object of this class or of a [derived class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php). If `FTL_Binding` is an [`interface`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) then `$tag` must be an object of a class that [`implements`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#language.oop5.interfaces.implements) `FTL_Binding`. On PHP 5 only arrays, classes and interfaces can be used as type hints. Since PHP 7, [scalar types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) can also be used.
- `$id` - no type declaration is provided, it can have any type. The `=` after the name says `$id` is optional. When it is not provided, the value after `=` (which is `null` here) is used instead.

When the function is called, only the values for its arguments must be placed between the parentheses. Like this:

```
// This works
$x = new FTL_Binding;
self::tag_foo($x, 123);        // $id is 123

// This also works
self::tag_foo($x);             // $id is NULL

// This doesn't work
self::tag_foo("abc");          // an object of type FTL_Binding was expected

// This also doesn't work
self::tag_foo(NULL, 123);      // NULL is also not an object of type FTL_Binding
```

Read more about [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and about function parameters [type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (aka "type hinting").